# how to resolve max search depth too small in SPIN model checker? What can be the possible reasons?

Tags: formal-verification, model-checking, spin, formal-methods

I am getting this error while doing my model verification, compilation string is

> spin -a tesTdma.pml
>
> Max search depth too small,
>   Depth = 9999 states

I do not understand the reason behind this error. Did someone came across this using ISPIN ver 1.1.4 and SPIN 6.4.7

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the search depth has been bounded, and you need to increase the bound by passing appropriate options to the generated verifier `pan`:

> `-b`
>
> bounded search mode, makes it an error to exceed the search depth, triggering and error trail
>
> `-mN`
>
> set max search depth to N steps (default N=10000)

See the [man page of `pan`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Pan.html),
and also the [man page of `spin`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Spin.html):

> `-run`
>
> Generate the verifier source code in `pan.c` (like `-a` does) and immediately compile and execute the verifier. Options that follow the `-run` argument are passed through to the compiler (options starting with `-[ODUE]` or to the verifier as runtime flags (all other options). Options to Spin itself should precede the `-run` argument.

The `-run` option is useful if you want to pass the options to `pan` via the call to `spin`, instead of separately.

Also, from slide 1 on page 27 in [these slides](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/SpinIntro.pdf):

> SPIN displays `“error: max search depth too small”` to let you know that the depth bound prevented it from searching the complete statespace.

Comment: Good Answer. I just want to comment that: **1.** on some problems using the option `-bfs` to perform a breadth first search helps circumventing the issue altogether **2.** in some cases the solution is not to increase the bound value, but re-engineering the model into a better system abstraction which is more suitable for verification